# How can I squeeze language practice into small chunks of time?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, online-learning

Since my time is very limited, the most success I have had with learning
languages has been with the [Babbel](https://babbel.com/) app; its focus on
small lessons (around 5-7 minutes) works well for me. However, there will
eventually come a time when I outgrow Babbel, since many of its courses
(Russian in particular) only cover upper-beginner and lower-intermediate study
of the language. I don't know anyone else who is studying the same languages,
and I don't live in an area with appropriate native speakers.

So, at intermediate and advanced levels of language study, how can I
effectively learn a language in small chunks of time, without the opportunity
to converse with native speakers regularly?

Comment: Could you please add what your learning goals are? What sort of things do you want to be able to do with your Russian? Specifying learning goals are essential for specifying learning methods.

Comment: Studying a textbook which incudes audio is pretty doable in small chunks. Most of the time, the audio dialogues are short enough (e.g. 10-15 minutes max).

Answer (score 1):

YouTube videos can be listened and watched while you do other chores such as dish washing.
Or while commuting
This is great for maximizing your efficiency

Many of them can require just 10 minutes of your time at a time. So you can watch one or two videos early in the morning when preparing And while having breakfast, etc